# How would I access the player's local mouse from a server-side script in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox-studio

I am creating a system that allows the player to still interact with ClickDetectors while using a Tool. I need to access the local player and mouse in a SERVER-side script. I am trying to make it so that when the item is unequipped, an enemy will ignore you. That part worked, but the ClickDetectors don't.

I have tried using RemoteEvents to pass along the local player and mouse target, but it didn't seem to work. The three scripts below are what I used:

Server-Side Script

```
local plr
local mouseTarget

game.ReplicatedStorage.Tool.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, mouseTarget2)
    plr = player
    mouseTarget = mouseTarget2
end)

print(plr, mouseTarget)

script.Parent.Equipped:Connect(function()
    game.ReplicatedStorage.LanternEvents.Equipped:FireClient(plr)
end)

script.Parent.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    game.ReplicatedStorage.LanternEvents.UnEquipped:FireClient(plr)
end)

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    if mouseTarget:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("ClickDetector") then
        if mouseTarget.Name == "Paper" then
            game.ReplicatedStorage.PaperEvents.PaperEvent1:FireClient(plr)
            plr.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.Classic
        elseif mouseTarget.Parent.Name == "Keypad" then
            game.ReplicatedStorage.KeypadEvent:FireClient(plr)
        elseif mouseTarget.Parent.Name == "Lighter" then
            game.Workspace.Values.CollectedLighter.Value = true
            mouseTarget:Destroy()
        else
            game.Workspace.Values.Collected.Value += 1
            mouseTarget:Destroy()
        end
    end
end)
```

Local Script:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local mouse = player:GetMouse()

local mouseTarget = mouse.Target

while wait(0.01) do
    game.ReplicatedStorage.Tool:FireServer(mouseTarget)
end
```

The Output is: Nil Nil.

Thank you in advance,
Programming_Good_Games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no understating how much of a bad idea this is.

Firstly, and most importantly, you should never be sending constant requests to the server since this will cause poor performance.
You should instead Listen to the RunService Heartbeat event ***on the client*** and check if the mouse is over one of the ClickDetectors, and only then Fire a RemoteEvent to the server, where the server will do a sanity check and act upon it.
You should almost never use a while wait(a very small number) loop since this does not take into account the Client's frame rate, so there will be a very high chance of you checking the exact same frame multiple times.

To continue, it is impossible to directly access the mouse from the server since the mouse only exists on the client.